# How to improve performance of changing files and folders permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, find, chmod

I setting up my work project permissions in series to:

- 755 for all directories
- 644 for all files

I do it by running next commands:

```
$ find /path/to/project -type d -exec chmod 0755 {};

$ find /path/to/project -type f -exec chmod 0644 {};
```

It works fine, but a bit **slowly**, especially on virtual machines.

Could I **improve** performance of this tasks in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reference** - [https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-chmod-all-directories-except-files-recursively][1]

1.Most of the time consumed here would go in loading the chmod process for every entry. In order to avoid that use xargs-

```
     find /path/to/project -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755 
     find /path/to/project -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

2.Fortunately, you can opt not to use `find` which can make it even faster.  The second answer in the reference link explains how to compose a chmod command for your needs

Comment: Thank you! Your reference link is very useful for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use directly the command [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod):

```
chmod -R a-x+X,u+rw,go+r-w /path/to/project
```

where `a-x+X` - remove the execute permission on all files in a directory tree (i.e. recursively), while allowing for directory browsing.

The construct `a-x+X` removes the execution bit (`-x`) for all (`a` , I.e. user, group and others) of any file and directory and then add it (`+X`) to all directories (and executable files as well, but no such a file exists because of the previous `-x`).
In a similar way `go+r-w` adds the read permission (`+r`) and removes the write permission (`-w`)  to group and others ( `go`).

Comment: Wow, it's very cool, thanks a lot! Could you explain a bit what do `a-x+X` option?

Comment: I've added some comments in case they can be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
find /path/to/project -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +
```

This will group as many arguments to `chmod` as possible.

Also, consider using `chmod -R` first, and maybe touch the directories afterwards.

Comment: I assumed `chmod -R` set permissions to *both* (files and directories) instead of files/directories *separately*, so it will change permissions incorrectly. What about `+` at the end - it's interesting idea, thanks!

Comment: I didn't say otherwise about `chmod -R`. Still, a full sweep with `chmod -R` and then just the dirs with `find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +` would be faster.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't understand first what you meant