# Fastest way to set access permissions for a large number of files / directories?

Tags: performance, shell, file-permissions, chmod

I want to set access permissions for a large number of files and directories. In [How to improve performance of changing files and folders permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30592771/5269892) and https://superuser.com/a/91938/813482, several variants to set permissions are presented, among others:

**Variant 1:**

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

**Variant 2:**

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755 
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

**Variant 3:**

```
chmod 755 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type d)
chmod 644 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type f)
```

Which of these should be the most efficient? In a quick test for the directory I'm using, compared to variant 1, variant 2 reduced the time from more than 30 to more than 3 sec (one order of magnitude), since it does not need to call `chmod` for every file separately. Variant 3 gave warnings, since some directory names/filenames contain spaces and it cannot access those directories. Variant 3 may even be slightly faster than variant 2, but I'm not sure since this may be related to not being able to enter the directories(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of these should be the most efficient?

Variant 1.

I you really want speed, traverse once, not twice.

```
find /path/to/base/dir '(' -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + ')' -o '(' -type f -exec chmod 644 {} + ')'
```

Variant 2 is great if the number of files or directories is greater than the maximum number of arguments on a platform.

Variant 3 is very bad, where the result of find is not quoted, and the shell will do word splitting and filename expansion. It will fail badly if any path has, for example, a space or a star.

Comment: I can see the speed advantage of traversing once. But variant 2 was faster when traversing twice compared to variant 1 when traversing twice. Shouldn't variant 2 with traversing once be even faster?

Comment: With how many millions of files have you tested on? I.e. I question the method of measurement. Also, I suspect that you tested version 2 after version 1, which means the paths were in the cache.

Comment: The directory has about 10400 files and 2800 directories. You are correct in that I ran variant 2 after variant 1. In any case, your solution (0.83s) is indeed faster than variant 2 (0.70 + 2.77 = 3.47s).